# PHP Securely transform $_GET / $_POST array

Tags: php, post, get, extract

I was checking my script for vulnerabilities and was shocked the way i used to do in the past which is extremely insecure:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

or shorter

```
extract( $_GET );
```

I altered with firebug some POST/GET variables to match a name i used in my script. they can be overwritten **if the name would be guessed correctly.**

So i thought i had to do it individually naming like this:
$allowed_vars =

```
$allowed_vars = array("time","hotfile","netload","megaupload","user","pfda","xyz","sara","amount_needed");
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
        {
             if (in_array($key,$allowed_vars))
                {
                    $$key = $value;
                }
        }
```

This way saves some time than naming them individually.

What kind of automation have to be used for this?

Comment: Why do you have to assign them into individual variables in the first place? Can't you just use `$_GET[ 'time' ]` and so on?

Comment: FYI, you'd put `$allowed_vars` outside the foreach, no reason to set it each time

Comment: @Juahana 1. ease-of-use, 2. prevent escaping. just coding style, not really the question here

Comment: @ben good point. corrected it

Comment: prevent escaping? what's this?

Comment: @col. in some cases its necessary to escape the ' or " . f.e. if the output will be saved as literal to write in a file/database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use any automatism of the kind.
I see no point in assigning request variables to global variables automatically.
If it's one or two variables, I  could deal with them manually.
If there are more, I'd rather keep them as array members for the convenient handling.

Yet I am using some sort of whitelisting approach similar to yours. 
but not to create global variables out of POST data but to add that data into SQL query.

Like in this simple helper function to produce SET statement:

```
function dbSet($fields) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}

$id     = intval($_POST['id']);
$fields = explode(" ","name surname lastname address zip fax phone");
$query  = "UPDATE $table SET ".dbSet($fields)." stamp=NOW() WHERE id=$id";
```

Comment: your last argument has something. i will reconsider my coding style.

Comment: @Email: this is a general case example, of course, you'd still want to make sure you got expected values; like a zip is really a zip, etc.  Also, if you want to use null values, you'll need to slightly alter this.

Answer (score 3):

You can save even more time by not extrating them at all.  Just use them from the $_GET array.  The advantages of this are not just avoiding collision with script variables (or worse) but also that you don't have to update that "automatism" when you add request parameters.

When I am working with POST data, as from a form, I often process each explicitly:

```
$data = array();
$data['field1'] = someSaniFunction($_POST['field1']);
$data['field2'] = someOtherFunction($_POST['field2']);
...
```

In this way I ensure that each field is properly handled, and only the fields I expect are touched.

Comment: i guess rewriting the automatism with 1 word saves more time than the additional time writing the variable with $_POST['something'] 2+ times

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you shouldn't transform data in the `$_REQUEST` array into variables using `$$` as it gives the possibility of overwriting variables held within the current scope.

Instead, you should consider having a request object or array in which you filter the data and only access named variables that you require. This way, you do not have to keep extending your allowed variable names and still maintain security.

The ZF for example has a request object, and they recommend using a input filter when working on this data:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extract function in a more secure way:

```
extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_SKIP);
```

This will not overwrite variables that already exist in your code. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) for other parameters you can use

Comment: However it is still the hole similar to register_globals - if you don't define a variable $admin for the regular user, it could be created this way.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel sure. Then you have to apply common sense and some developer skills to avoid that kind of situations.. :)

Comment: i'd rather avoid extract() function

Comment: extract doesn't solve the problem. it also uses cpu by putting in memory at large arrays and scans the script deeply. insecure

Comment: I didn't say is the better option.. I just pointed that you can do it a little bit more secure adding some parameters..